# Error: The build restored NuGet packages. Build the project again to include these packages in the build. For more information

Tags: c#, nuget

When I build my project for the first time the build succeeds, but when I Publish the project, the build fails and I get several errors that say:

> The build restored NuGet packages. Build the project again to include these packages in the build. For more information, see the below link
>   http://www.postsharp.net/links/nuget-restore.

What does this mean? And what can I do?

Comment: Did you follow the link in the error message? If not, why not? If so, what do you not understand about what you found there?

Comment: I donwt understand what they say to do. And what that they say to do it's not sucsess: `The term 'NuGet.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Try run Build Solution and restart visual studio.
It did the job for me.

Comment: I rebuilt just the project that was being referenced by this build error and that seems to have fixed it. I had to repeat this in order to actually get the startup project to start- the error came back, but rebuilding just that problem project fixed it again. Seems like a bug in VS. In any case, I did not have to restart VS.

Comment: This worked, after spending way too much time trying to figure out a different solution. "Did you try turning it off and back on again?"

Comment: Rebuilding after restarting Visual Studio worked for me. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 17):

Cleaning the solution before rebuild fixed this for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me, issue with one of the project where I had duplicates for nuget with different version in packages.config which stopped the project in downloading packages from nuget.org. Removing duplicate entry in packages.config worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you that are migrating old .NET 4.7.X project to .NET Core, this error may be thrown because you have a reference to the Bcl.Build package in your project file, like the following :

```
  <Target Name="EnsureBclBuildImported" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild" Condition="'$(BclBuildImported)' == ''">
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.14\tools\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets')" Text="This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317567." HelpKeyword="BCLBUILD2001" />
    <Error Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.14\tools\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets')" Text="The build restored NuGet packages. Build the project again to include these packages in the build. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317568." HelpKeyword="BCLBUILD2002" />
  </Target>
```

Removing this Target node entirely solved the problem for me.